# ARC calling non ARC non autoreleased method

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a program that uses ARC and call in some library methods that are non ARC.

Non ARC Library:

```
-(NSMutableData*) bar{
    return [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:100];
}
```

ARC Program:

```
- (void)foo
{
    NSMutableData* data = [d bar];
}
// Data is leaked
```

Is possible to avoid data being leaked without change the library method to return an autoreleased object?

When i use this library in Non ARC code i used to call release on data and thus avoid the leak.

Comment: Your non-ARC library is broken.  Fix it.  You'll be far better off in the long run if you.

Comment: A basic memory management rule says (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) "You own any object you create ... using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”". Since this is not the case for method "bar", the ARC program assumes that it is not the owner of the object instantiated in bar, and so it leaks. The only correct way to fix it is to return an autorelease object, as Lithu T.V suggested.

Comment: There is also the possibility of mark the method with NS_RETURNS_RETAINED which was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
-(NSMutableData*) bar
{
    return [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:100] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: in my question i wrote "without change the library method"

Comment: OK, i will the thing is lot of code depend on the behavior, and that code must to be fixed too.

Comment: Guaranteed that fixing it now will be less work than fixing it later when yet more code relies on it unless you toss the library altogether.